# Remove all pinned apps in start menu using power shell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11

Im making a script that cleans a fresh install of windows 11 to my liking. Does anybody know of a way to unpin all apps in start menu using PowerShell? I have [found scripts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0807efdf-2138-4655-acd5-d9a9b1298157/unpin-apps-with-powershell?forum=win10itprogeneral) but those scripts are name dependent, what if windows just feels to include a new app there.

I have read that the pinned apps are inside the

```
%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState
```

But when i went to this location, its a binary :( i would have thought that here contains all the shortcuts but i guess not

I know where all start menu apps are : `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, but i dont care about that since its not front and center, its those pinned apps that i would like to remove

[image]

EDIT:

Frankensteining some code

```
function Pin-App {    param(
        [string]$appname,
        [switch]$unpin
    )
    try{
        if ($unpin.IsPresent){
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Von "Start" lösen|Unpin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' unpinned from Start"
        }else{
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'An "Start" anheften|Pin to Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' pinned to Start"
        }
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?): '$appname' "
    }
}



$list = (Get-StartApps).Name; 
@($list).Count

foreach ($item in $list) {
    Pin-App $item -unpin
};
```

This seem to work but it started unpinning some weird stuff for example

```
App 'Firefox' unpinned from Start
```

but firefox is still here

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and add links to the scripts that don't fulfill your requirements. Maybe these could be used as a starting point.

Comment: Try something like `$list = (Get-StartApps).Name;
foreach ($item in $list) {Unpin-StartApp -Name $item};` let me know whether or not this helps resolve.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle  it throws me an error `The term 'Unpin-StartApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program.` do i need to install something for that to work?

Comment: How about this: `$list = (Get-StartLayout -LayoutPath $env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartApps.json).StartApps;
foreach ($item in $list) {Remove-StartPin -AppID $item.AppID};`

Comment: Oh, actually ensure that PowerShell is running the x64 version of PowerShell when you run the first command and that it is not running from x86 version of PowerShell. Not sure if you are using PowerShell.exe, Visual Studio Code, or PowerShell_ISE.exe but regardless I believe the issue is the x86 does not recognize those commands where the x64 version would perhaps see: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1964 buried in comments to help me draw this conclusion.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle im not sure if im runnning the x64 since it does not say (im sure it did not run the x84) , i also tried running in terminal powershell v7. Can i check within powershell which versionn im running in?

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle As for the seconnd code you have given `The term 'Get-StartLayout' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.`

Comment: If you get true then it is x64 running `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`. If you get false, then it is x86. Please let me know what you see when you run that from PowerShell.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle indeed i am getting `TRUE`. Here is a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/XDVcGLx) of the terminal with the error. I ran it on powershell pre installed on windows the v5

Comment: I was playing with some code, and have noticed that `$list = (Get-StartApps).Name` have 310 items in it, isnt that too many?

Answer (score 2):

I found a not so great way but works. All you have to do is take the start2.bin file from another machine that has been setup to your liking or completely blank and use a script to taskkill explorer.exe and move the bin over to the folder

`%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState`

I took a Windows 11 Home version bin and moved it to an Enterprise version (Sandbox on another machine) and seemed to work just fine.

I should mention, it is start2.bin due to these machines being 22H2.

This **WILL NOT** change the menu for every user automatically.

**IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE ALL PINNED APP FROM ALL USERS AUTOMATICALLY DO THIS**

**Create** a new directory listing like this

```
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState
```

Copy over the same start2.bin file and everything else in this user directory from the donor pc and paste it in here. Change the file permissions to **SYSTEM** as the owner.

[New Directory Created And All The Files Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzHsO.png)

**EDIT:** If you want to make every new user that signs in have **preset** pins you should be able to modify/add these files here.

`C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`

**`Note: this will not remove Edge, Settings, and Explorer from being pinned.`**

Create a file `LayoutModification.json` and setup the default pinned apps you would like in this format.

[THIS WILL CREATE A LAYOUT LIKE THIS FROM MY EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM42T.png)

`{"primaryOEMPins":[{"desktopAppLink":"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Outlook.lnk"},{"desktopAppLink":"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Google Chrome.lnk"},{"desktopAppLink":"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Excel.lnk"}]}`

Everytime a new user logs in it should setup like you like it.

I am also using this registry setup on the default user to modify each new user at first login

```
::THIS INSTALLS REGISTRY ITEMS INTO THE DEFUALT REGISTRY HIVE:

::THIS IS LOADS THE DEFAULT HIVE FOR ALL USERS
reg load HKLM\DEFAULT c:\users\default\ntuser.dat
::THIS MIGHT REMOVE TIKTOK AND OTHER JUNK FROM START MENU ON NEW USER LOGIN/CREATE
REG ADD "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent" /v DisableCloudOptimizedContent /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent" /v DisableConsumerAccountStateContent /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\default\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent" /v DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
reg add "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager" /v ContentDeliveryAllowed /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f
reg add "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager" /v SilentInstalledAppsEnabled /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f
reg add "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager" /v SystemPaneSuggestionsEnabled /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f
::THIS Disables Privacy Settings Experience Using Registry TESTED ON W11 AND WORKS
REG ADD "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OOBE" /v DisablePrivacyExperience /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
::THIS CHANGES TASKBAR TO THE LEFT
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v TaskbarAl /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
::THIS REMOVES WIDGETS FROM TASKBAR
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v TaskbarDa /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
::THIS REMOVES SEARCH FROM TASKBAR
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" /v SearchboxTaskbarMode /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
::THIS REMOVES TASK VIEW FROM TASKBAR
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v ShowTaskViewButton /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
::THIS REMOVES CHAT FROM TASKBAR
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v TaskbarMn /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
::THIS DISABLE CLOUD CONTENT SEARCH FOR ALL USERS
REG ADD "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search" /v AllowCloudSearch /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
::THIS IS DARK MODE
Reg.exe add "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize" /v "AppsUseLightTheme" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
Reg.exe add "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize" /v "SystemUsesLightTheme" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
::THIS IS EXPLORER TO THIS PC
Reg.exe add "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "LaunchTo" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
::THIS IS REMOVE QUICK ACCESS
Reg.exe add "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" /v HubMode /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
::THIS IS TO SHOW FILE NAME EXTENSIONS
Reg.exe add "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
:STOPPING EDGE FROM PRELOADING
REG ADD "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\TabPreloader" /f /v AllowTabPreloading /t REG_DWORD /d 0
REG ADD "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Main" /f /v AllowPrelaunch /t REG_DWORD /d 0
::THIS DELETES THE ONEDRIVE SETUP FOR NEW USERS BUT SHOULD STILL ALLOW
reg delete "HKLM\default\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v OneDriveSetup /f
::THIS REMOVES HOME FROM NAVIGATION
REG ADD "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" /f /v HubMode /t REG_DWORD /d 1
REG DELETE "HKLM\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace_36354489\{f874310e-b6b7-47dc-bc84-b9e6b38f5903}" /f
::THIS SHOWS MORE APPS IN START MENU
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /f /v Start_Layout /t REG_DWORD /d 1
::THIS SHOWS RECENTLY OPENED ITEMS IN START MENU
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /f /v Start_TrackDocs /t REG_DWORD /d 1
::THIS HIDES RECENTLY ADDED APPS IN START MENU
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /f /v HideRecentlyAddedApps /t REG_DWORD /d 1
::THIS HIDES MOST USED APPS IN START MENU
REG ADD "HKLM\default\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /f /v ShowOrHideMostUsedApps /t REG_DWORD /d 2

::THIS ENABLES THE OLDER STYLE CONTEXTUAL MENUS
reg add "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v FullContext /d "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c reg add \"HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32\" /v \"\" /f" /f
::THIS IS TASKBAND FOR ALL USERS
reg add "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v CustomTaskbandFavorites /d "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c REG ADD \"HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband\" /v Favorites /t REG_BINARY /d \"ff\" /f" /f
reg add "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v CustomTaskbandFavoritesResolve /d "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c REG ADD \"HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband\" /v FavoritesResolve /t REG_BINARY /d \"\" /f" /f
::THIS IS A TASK TO REBOOT EXPLORER ON FIRST LOGIN
reg add "HKLM\default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v Restart /d "powershell -Command Stop-Process -Processname Explorer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -force" /f
::THIS UNLOADS THE DEFAULT HIVE
reg unload HKLM\DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead.

```
Import-Module StartLayout

# Get the list of pinned apps in the Start menu
$apps = Get-StartApps 

# Unpin the apps from the Start menu
foreach ($app in $apps) {
    $appId = $app.AppId
    $packageName = $appId.Split('_')[0]
    $packageFullName = (Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.PackageFamilyName -eq $packageName}).PackageFullName
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $folder = $shell.Namespace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}')
    $item = $folder.Parsename("$packageName!App")
    $verb = $item.Verbs() | Where-Object {$_.Name.replace('&', '') -eq 'Unpin from Start'}
    $verb.DoIt()
}
```

Comment: I tried running your script sir and it did not remove any items. I tried doing `echo $item.Name` the list it gave me are the files in my desktop not the pinned apps in the start menu

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I changed it and tested it in my sandbox. now it works for sure.

Comment: I get an error at line before `$verb.DoIt()` saying `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` I tried printing variables to debug and it would seems that packageFullName is empty